# How can I make my local server case-sensitive?

Tags: windows, xampp

I'm on Windows Vista Home Premium 64 bit OS. I use Apache Friends XAMPP server as my localhost. And I develop PHP, MySQL.

The problem is my local server is tolerant of case mistakes, especially in file/folder names.

When that running program on my server goes on linux servers, it's really a headache to locate and correct all the case errors.

So how can I make my local server case-sensitive as in linux servers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make an Apache running on Windows case-sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507156/can-i-make-an-apache-running-on-windows-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. PHP file handling is dependant on the underlying O. Since Windows is a case-insensitive OS, it cannot handle files with a different case.

This won't change, as it will break a lot of applications. NTFS is a case-sensitive filesystem according to this KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625).

If you have an old PC doing nothing, install a Linux server on it. Or if you have enough resources (RAM), run a Virtual machine ([with VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for example)

Answer (score 2):

case-sensitivity is not due to the web server it self, but to the operating system.
Linux is case-sensitive not windows. As far as i know, you can't make windows case-sensitive.

but try yo keep all your folders/files lowercase, this will save you much headeach when moving to linux production server.