# Make WAMP server check for case sensitivity (or IDE)

Tags: linux, windows, apache, symfony

I am developing a web app with PHPstorm on a Symfony 2 framework. Sometimes I run into a problem based on case sensitivity of the machine I deploy the project to (Linux Server).

What I am looking for is a way to make the IDE register errors based on case sensitivity on my Windows system or to force a case sensitive behaviour of the Apache. Any Idea how to solve this problem without setting up a virtual Linux machine in my developing environment?

The problem arises, when I am referencing files or templates and have a kind of typo which is not recognized by Windows because it's not case sensitive. When deployed to the "live" System, something stops working and it's not easy to find the error without changing to "development mode" - especially, when there were a lot of changes since last update.

Any idea or link to more info is appreciated. If there's no way around I will set up a Linux on a virtual machine but it's just not as convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. There are several answers in SO relative to this topic:

[How can I make my local server case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582845/how-can-i-make-my-local-server-case-sensitive)

[Can I make an Apache running on Windows case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507156/can-i-make-an-apache-running-on-windows-case-sensitive)

Comment: Hi, thanx a lot for those links. Couldn't find them when searching. Probably used the wrong keywords, since I was searching for both systems and not Windows plus Apache alone.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel you're welcome :) please vote up if it helped or make it solved if you feel answers your question